# Rangy: how do I expand the selection based on parent node?

Tags: javascript, rangy

html that is being selected:

```
some te<b>xt here is bold</b>ed, I guess
              |______________________|  <- the selection range
```

so, the selected .toHtml() is this:

```
<b>ere is bold</b>ed, I gue
```

but this is not in the original document.

So, what I want to do is expand the selection so that it contains the entire BOLD tag.

This is easy to detect, as you just need to do a test if

```
a = rangy.getSelection()
a.anchorNode.parentElement != a.focusNode.parentElement
```

The documentation states that rangy ranges have a `setStartBefore(Node)` method : http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/RangyRange

so, I get the current range

```
b = a.getRangeAt(0)
```

and try to setStartBefore :

```
b.setStartBefore(a.anchorNode.parentNode)
```

and since I'm doing this all in the console, I get the immediate feedback saying

```
undefined
```

what would be causing this, and how I would go around it to find a solution for the problem I want to solve?

UPDATE:
as per Tim Down's suggestion, I've tried the following:
[image]
Original Text:
[image]

It should have expanded to include ***Mass Ef*** shouldn't it have?

UPDATE 2:

The solution (as per Tim Down)
[image]

Comment: The solution provided in the question is actually not a real solution. If it was, 'b.canSurroundContents()' would return 'true'. I am trying to do the same but still couldn't get 'b.canSurroundContents' to return true. Any ideas?

Comment: I have asked here in detail, with examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141992/with-rangy-even-though-i-extend-the-range-by-setstartbefore-method-containsnod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reselect the range:

```
a.setSingleRange(b);
```

By the way `parentElement` is not universally supported: it started out IE only, has relatively recently made it into the [DOM4 spec](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#parent-element) and is not yet supported in Firefox ([support is coming in Firefox 9.0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.parentElement), apparently). You'll need a workaround based on `parentNode` and `nodeType`.

Comment: I'm not too worried about browser compatibility atm. but I appreciate the warning, as I'll have to worry about it soon-ish. I've updated my question with my results from trying a.setSingleRange(b);

Comment: @TheLindyHop: From that screenshot, it looks like you haven't done anything (`setStartBefore()` etc.) to the range before reselecting it.

Comment: Excellent, I'll post a screen shot of what I've done to make it work for future people with problems.